# How to find if DST was applicable during a given date?

Tags: c#, datetime, iana

Is dotnet TimeZoneInfo safe to find out whether DST was applicable during a given date?

```
bool isDaylight = TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(anyTime);
```

EDIT: Pardon my ignorance, DST is not applicable in our country. My understanding is that DST start & end is decided every year differently in each country wherever applicable. How a dotnet data-structure, without any internet service can predict if a given date was DST?

Comment: It is not decided differently from year to year, but the rules are different between different countries. In EU, the rule is: Start at the last sunday in march and stop at the last sunday in october.

Comment: "How a dotnet data-structure, without any internet service can predict if a given date was DST?" The list of time adjustment rules (for all time zones) is maintained by the OS. Updates to this list (which are governed by political bodies, not any logical rules) are generally distributed through Windows Update.

Comment: Set of time zones depends on specific OS version / updates / hotfixes etc. In windows for example if country change DST / time zones you need to install updates to local OS